# Tension in a string attached to a spring with deformation at a point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, equilibrium, stress-strain

I am trying to calculate the tension in a string in the configuration shown in the diagram below. Here is a verbal description of the setup:
The string is fixed at one end with the other end connected to a spring. The spring, with constant $K$, is limited to only vertical movement. The string begins with a tension $T$, which causes the free end of the spring to extend from its resting position $S_0$ to position $S_0+S$ such that the following relationship is upheld:$$F_s=K\cdot S=T\cdot\frac{h}{\sqrt{D^2+h^2}}$$ A distance $x$ along the horizontal from the fixed end of the string, a force $F$ is applied vertically downward. This force is such that the string is forced into the configuration shown with a tension $T_1$. The spring will naturally extend to accommodate this deformation until the free end is $h_1$ above the horizontal line defined by the segment labeled $x$. It seems to me that if the string has cross-sectional area $A$ and Young's modulus $Y$ then it should be possible to determine the tension $T_1$ as a function of $A$, $Y$, $x$, $T$, $D$, and $h$.
[image: Diagram]
$S_0$ is not relevant to the calculation at all. I can calculate $S$ using $$S=\frac{T}{K}\cdot\frac{h}{\sqrt{D^2+h^2}}$$ I should be able to calculate $$T_1=K(S+h-h_1)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{(D-x)^2+h_1^2}}{h_1}$$ and from previous problems I know that I can calculate $$T_1=(T+AY)\frac{x+\sqrt{(D-x)^2+h_1^2}}{\sqrt{D^2+h^2}}-AY$$ However, I can't for the life of me find a way to write $h_1$ in terms of the other variables so that I can remove it from either equation for $T_1$. I think it should be possible since $h_1$ is simply an equilibrium point, but I've been unable to work it out myself. I'm probably missing something obvious, but some other eyes on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the length of the rope remains constant. At first the length is given by:

$$L=\sqrt{D^2+h^2}$$

After applying the force, the length is given by:

$$L=x+\sqrt{(D-x)^2+h_1^2}$$

By assuming $L$ is constant, one can derive an expression for $h_1$:

$$\sqrt{D^2+h^2}=x+\sqrt{(D-x)^2+h_1^2}$$

$$\left(\sqrt{D^2+h^2}-x\right)^2=(D-x)^2+h_1^2$$

$$h_1 = \pm \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{D^2+h^2}-x\right)^2-(D-x)^2}$$

Comment: Yes I can solve it if I assume the length is constant, but I'm trying to account for the stretching of the string under tension.